# How to upload html document using Docusign REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I have my code working to upload a PDF document, but I am trying to get it to upload an HTML document and having trouble. My code that works for the PDF document is this:

```
                $documents = new Document();
                $documents->setName($doc_name . '.pdf');
                $documents->setDocumentId(1);
                $documents->setFileExtension('pdf');
                $file = file_get_contents($file_url);
                $documents->setDocumentBase64(base64_encode($file));
```

But when I try to do this with an HTML document it fails. My HTML attempt uses this:

```
                $documents = new Document();
                $documents->setName($doc_name . '.pdf');
                $documents->setDocumentId(1);
                $documents->setFileExtension('html');
                $documents->setDocumentBase64(base64_encode($html));
```

When I try this using the REST API Explorer I get this error message:

> System was unable to convert this document to a PDF. Unable to convert Document(SampleHTML) to a PDF. Error: UserId:xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx IPAddress:54.213.184.61 Source:ApiRESTv2:FileType UNKNOWN is ineligible for conversion.

I have read that html is an accepted file type, so I am pretty sure this is possible. I could cover to PDF on my server and send, but would rather pass that off to Docusign.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DocuSign platform does indeed accept multiple document formats, however there may be a difference between what the DS Apps accept and what the API accepts.  The list of supported document types that you can send through the DocuSign Console can be found here:

https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-supported-file-formats

However I'm not sure if `.html` is an accepted file format when sending **through the API**.  I thought there might be security issues with that but not positive at this point.  In either case, even though you are setting the `fileExtension` property it looks like you are still sending a document with a filename that ends with `.pdf`, have you tried removing that or changing to `.html`?

Comment: Thanks! This was a big help.